# $E[ f(Z) \cdot Z] =E[Z^2]$ iff $f(z)=z$

Tags: probability-theory, expectation

Suppose $f(\cdot)$ is a fucntion that is odd, $f(0)=0$, increasing and continuous.Is the following result true

> Let  $Z \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$ then  \begin{align} \mathbb E[ f(Z) \cdot Z]
>  =\mathbb E[Z^2] \end{align} iff $f(z)=z$ a.s.

Clearly, if $f(z)=z$ than the statement follows, but is the reverse direction true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about $f(z) = \frac{1}{3}z^3$? This gives

$$ \Bbb{E}[f(Z)Z] = \frac{1}{3}\Bbb{E}[Z^4] = 1 = \Bbb{E}[Z^2]. $$

In general, if $g$ is an odd measurable function such that $\Bbb{E}[Z g(Z)]$ is finite and positive ($Zg(Z)$ is always non-negative, so the expectation is well-defined and takes values in $[0, \infty]$), then

$$f(z) = \frac{g(z)}{\Bbb{E}[Zg(Z)]}$$

always satisfies $\Bbb{E}[Zf(Z)] = \Bbb{E}[Z^2]$.

Comment: Can we show that $f(z)$ satisfies this iff $\lim_{z \to \infty} f(z)=\infty$?

Comment: @Boby, I'm afraid you can't. As you can see from my answer, you can literally choose almost any odd function $f$ up to constant multiple. For instance, consider $f(z) = \frac{cz}{1+z^2}$ where $c > 0$ is chosen so that $\Bbb{E}[f(Z)Z] = 1$.